# PhoneGap Take picture and set FILE_URI as value of input

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a phoneGap app that takes a picture and sets the value of a file input to the FILE_URI taken from the onCameraSuccess of getPicture.

When I alert the value of the file input, I get file:// .. . 
That means setting the value of the input file was successful.

but when PHP on a server recieves the form, the file input is empty.
I tried echoing $_FILES["Customer_image"]["name"] but it's empty.

Did I miss something?
is that allowed?

Comment: can you post your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set the location of a file input and upload a file that way. On PhoneGap, you can use the `upload()` method of the `FileTransfer` object to upload a file based on the URI. See the docs here...

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer

Comment: Thanks, I discovered it from another answer here in stackoverflow, but thanks for the link!